# Android Dialog contents don't fit

Tags: android

I am trying to create a popup Dialog that contains 6 NumberPickers and 2 buttons. My problem is that the last NumberPicker goes off the edge of the dialog as seen here in red (It doesnt actually appear on screen):
[image]
Below is the XML code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/np"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:layout_below="@+id/np"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/np"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in code I use it simply with:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(EditTextActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.registration_picker_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Edit Year");
```

Is there anything in the XML I can do to make it shrink the NumberPickers width to fit?

Comment: On each `NumberPicker`, set the `layout_width` to `0dp`, and the `layout_weight` to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each NumberPicker use the `layout_weight` attribute to give each control 1/6th of the container.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/np"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:weightSum="1.0">  <!-- Added weightSum -->

    <!-- added layout_weight -->
    <NumberPicker android:layout_weight="0.167"  
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

    <!-- added layout_weight -->
    <NumberPicker android:layout_weight="0.167"  
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

    <!-- added layout_weight -->
    <NumberPicker android:layout_weight="0.167" 
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

    <!-- added layout_weight -->
    <NumberPicker android:layout_weight="0.167"  
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

    <!-- added layout_weight -->
    <NumberPicker android:layout_weight="0.167"  
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

    <!-- added layout_weight -->
    <NumberPicker android:layout_weight="0.167" 
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I was under the impression it would pack it all tightly for me, but I might be thinking too much in  terms of javax.swing